# Issues with Import from sibling directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

This question is in context of python 2.7 and relative imports. I have gone through related questions and things are still not working for me. I don't know what am I missing here?

Following is my dir hierarchy

```
.
|-> wrapper.py
|-> __init__.py
|-> util
|    |-> hello.py
|    |-> __init__.py
|-> src
|    |-> wrapper.py
|    |-> __init__.py
```

All **__init__.py** are blank files only to "treat the directories as containing packages"

Following is how ./util/hello.py reads. This has its own main function and can run of its own.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This is hello.py.

import sys

# Define a main() function that prints a little greeting.
def main():
  print "Hello World!!!"

# Standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Following is how ./wrapper.py reads. This also has its own main function and uses ./util/hello.py to achieve its goal.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This is wrapper.py.

import sys
from util import hello

# Define a main() function that prints a little greeting.
def main():
    hello.main()        # This prints "Hello World!!!"

# Standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Following is how ./src/wrapper.py reads.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This is wrapper.py.

import sys
from ..util import hello

# Define a main() function that prints a little greeting.
def main():
    hello.main()        # This prints "Hello World!!!"

# Standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you see, It's almost exact copy of ./wrapper.py with minimal changes to make it run (changes in import). All **__init__.py** are present too. However any attempt to run it gives following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..util import hello
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

However, if I import hello.py as following it works:

```
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("../util/"))
import hello
```

Two Questions:

Q1. What am I doing wrong or what is missing my attention?

Q2. How can I code **./src/__init__.py** such that just "import hello" works in ./src/wrapper.py?

Comment: How are you running the `./wrapper.py`? Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py

Comment: There are many existing answers which address Q1, simply search for "Attempted relative import in non-package". I can not answer Q2, because the question leads in the wrong direction. You *can* run `python -m src.wrapper`, then `import hello` likewise `from hello import hello` works in `src/wrapper.py`. I think it is considered wise to avoid relative imports from locations other than the top-level in general!

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: Running in "./src" as "python wrapper.py".

Comment: @Michael Hoff: Didn't quite get you with "python -m src.wrapper". What to do and where. What does it do?

Comment: FYI, From inside `./src` I want to run `./src/wrapper.py` as `python wrapper.py`. From inside `./src`, I tried running it as `python -m ..util wrapper.py`. It didn't work, with following error (Python 2.7.12):
`/usr/bin/python: Relative module names not supported`

Comment: No, my solution assumes you are executing python in the *root* directory. As the error message indicates, it does apparently not work with relative package names.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you need to have a parent package for all your code. You can't just put `__init__.py` in the root directory and expect it to behave as a package.

I'll split your options into good and bad, starting with the bad:

**Bad - relative imports:**
What you should do is put *all* your code (aka `.`) in a package named appropriately (`src` is a bad name for a package btw). Say `mypackage`. Then you'll be able to import `src.wrapper` only as `mypackage.src.wrapper`, from places where it is available on the python path, like a python interpreter open in the directory *containing* `mypackage`. Installing the package also makes it available on the path.

For more information on relative imports and why they are bad:

- [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=relative+imports

**Good - non-relative imports:**
The better approach is import through the package in an absolute manner. You still have to create a parent package `mypackage`, but this time you get rid of the relative imports and use `import mypackage.util.hello` from *inside* `wrapper.py`. For this to work you have to set the python path to include the directory containing `mypackage`.

The recommended way to do this is create a `setup.py` file and install your package. For development you should use `python setup.py develop` or `pip install -e .`

More on python packaging: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/

Edit:
for your Q2, if you use absolute imports you can use `import mypackage.util.hello as hello` or `from mypackage.util import hello`. Both are the same.

In some special cases you may be interested in writing `import util.hello as hello` inside `/mypackage/__init__.py`, and then you could use `from mypackage import hello` etc.